# Getting AttributeError when using pickle on a python function

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I am getting the below error when loading an pickled functiond

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Can't get attribute 'customer_transform' on <module '__main__' from '/var/runtime/bootstrap.py'>",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/on_demand_dataset_load_and_transform/handler.py\", line 14, in lambda_handler\n    return transform_data(load_response, udf_s3_key)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/on_demand_dataset_load_and_transform/transform_data.py\", line 26, in transform_data\n    udf = pickle.loads(udf_bytes)\n"
  ]
}
```

I am using jupyter notebook to write a function, pickle it and store it in S3.

```
def customer_transform(input):
     # implementation

import pickle

def serialize_func(func):
    return pickle.dumps(func)

serialized_transform = serialize_func(customer_transform)

s3_client.put_object(Body=serialized_transform, Bucket="Bucket_name", Key="key")
```

When I try to read data from S3 and unpickle it, I am getting the above error. Below is the code

```
udf_bytes = s3_client.get_object(Bucket="Bucket_name", Key="key")["Body"].read()

downloaded_func = pickle.loads(udf_bytes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this importing `dill`

```
import dill as pickle
```

Here is the documentation for [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill)

Comment: Probably worth sharing what dill is: https://pypi.org/project/dill/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).